# Quick Look and UIWebView supported file types

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiwebview, quicklook

Is there an updated list of file types that can be displayed using `UIWebView` that ships with **iOS 6.0**?  I am aware of the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html) and [an earlier question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320220/file-formats-supported-by-uiwebview) about this topic.  However, both are outdated and don't list all supported types.  For example, `.mov` and `.m4a` types can be displayed using the `UIWebView` but aren't listed in the doc.  The same question goes for Quick Look types.  [Its doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) also hasn't been updated since 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The back-end of UIWebView is WebKit (same thing used by Safari and other major browsers.)  Whatever WebKit supports, UIWebView supports that, too.

This is also true in terms of how it displays/renders pages, HTML-5, etc.

*NOTE*: keep in mind which version of WebKit is in which version of iOS.  I don't think it changes that often, but it's something to keep in mind when major feature updates come along.