# How to open .csv link in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I  want  to open .csv link in the UIWebView. I am getting link some .csv links from the web how to open that link in the UIWebView. I am using the below code

```
  NSString *urlString = @"https://xoxoengage-images-test.s3.amazonaws.com/image/clients/gxoxo/annoucement/XXXXdetails201805021526899124.csv";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webviewobj loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

but the result is shown in the below image, help me out to sort this issue.[image: when i open url in webview]

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebView doesn't support the CSV format natively.
See this: [File Formats Supported by UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320220/file-formats-supported-by-uiwebview)

If your server returns "text/plain" (or you have this file as ".txt") you'll see its raw text in the web view.

If you want a grid table view, then you need to convert csv to to one of the supported formats. The obvious choice would be HTML.

If you can convert on the server side - that's better, otherwise download the csv file, parse it line by line, and output as HTML. Load the HTML into the web view. [loadHTMLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617979-loadhtmlstring?language=objc) is what you could use.

Also with UIWebView this can be done sort of transparently using a custom [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocol).

This might be helpful: [Where can I find a CSV to NSArray parser for Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks for the  quick response can we convert link to some pdf or other formate and open in webview .

Comment: Yes you can. But you have to write code to do it on the iOS side. Apple APIs don't convert it from CSV for you. If you are going to have to write code, the easiest is to convert CSV to HTML.

Comment: can you please give me the code to convert csv to html

Comment: Here is the start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c

Comment: but gmail is opening the .cvs link, how they are doing it